# Unity 3d shooter tutorial animation

Tags: 3d, animation, unity

I'm following [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter-project) tutorial. I cannot get even simple animations to work. Here's a very simple case that was supposed to work but did not:

1. Add an animator component to the 'player' prefab
2. Create an animator controller and drag it to the corresponding field in the player animator component.
3. Open the 'animator' tab (right click on animator controller -> open), and drag an animation clip. This automatically becomes the default state.
4. Click play. Nothing happens. In the animator tab I can see a blue progress bar in the 'default' state (the only animation I dragged to the state machine). But the game screen shows no animation.

#### The player prefab inspector:

[image: The player inspector]

#### The very simple state machine

[image]
This is driving me nuts.

Comment: I have no idea what the structure behind your animations are is, so I could be wrong, but shouldn't the "Idle" animation be activated from "Any State"?

Comment: Yes. But should not this work? "Go to idle upon entry and stay there" is what I thought. I will try with any state and get back

Comment: Tried Any State -> Idle. Did not change anything. Also, the orange transition line from Entry to Idle was put there by unity. It's enforced by default.

Comment: Your Avatar is not set in the Inspector. Are you setting it up elsewhere?

Comment: No I'm not. Is it required? The tutorial video did not mention it. I neverthless tried assigning it the included 'player' avatar. It did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the player prefab and re-adding it did the trick When I added the player again, the 'player' avatar was automatically assigned to it. I did not have to do it manually. And this 'magically' solved the issue somehow.